# Any way to create an instance from an AppDomain in .NET when then instance lacks public constructor?

Tags: .net, appdomain

I need to create an instance of a class using an AppDomain. The class, however, does not have a public constructor; it is created through a static method. Is there any way of doing this or does it have to have a public constructor?

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static MyClass CreateInstance(int arg1, string arg2, string arg3)
   {
      return new MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   }
   internal MyClass(int arg1, string arg2, string arg3){};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a helper class, one that you can create through a normal constructor call. You would then have a method on it that invokes the static method on `MyClass` and returns instances to you. A `MyClassFactory`, if you will.